# Can cfvideo tag from Railo be used under Adobe CF?

Tags: coldfusion, railo

Just started something related to video.  It would really help if we can use cfvideo.  Any idea if that's doable?

Comment: I assume you are asking how you might go about extracting the railo functionality (the literal code used there) and make use of it under Adobe CF.  Could you clarify that in your question?

Comment: Yes, I'm wondering if it is straight forward to port the cfvideo tag over to work under ACF.  If it isn't, or if Railo's license prohibits one to do that, then any tips on 3rd party lib for providing similar functionality to cfvideo would be helpful, thank yoou.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know about CFVIDEO specifically, but my VideoConverter.cfc will allow you to convert video to different formats and play video universally.

https://github.com/sebtools/Video-Converter

Like CFVIDEO, it uses ffmpeg in the background. So I imagine it could be enhanced to add other functionality from CFVIDEO as well.

It runs on ColdFusion and I would think it should run on Railo or OpenBD as well.

Comment: I'm not looking into re-encoding.  I just being able to read the media file metadata and create thumbnails.  Thanks

Comment: It does both of those things. I just updated the readme to cover both of those requirements.

Answer (score 4):

`<CFVIDEO>` is free... Perhaps we have some links Left that presume otherwise, apologies if that's the case... Anyway it is free. But the problem rather is how to extend ACF with it since the core is different. But having an open source engine allows anyone to use the code and adjust it as needed.

BTW, we us ffmpeg in the. background as well and cfvideo is just a wrapper.

Comment: Can you please point me to the right package that's responsible for cfvideo?  I can only find the interfaces... thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In short, no, not directly.  The `CFVIDEO` tag in Railo is a Railo-specific add-on for Railo and is not available for Adobe ColdFusion.  As Gert pointed out, the code for Raio's `CFVIDEO` tag may be available and you could reverse-engineer it into a custom tag for Adobe ColdFusion, but the tag itself is not part of the `CFML` language as Adobe supports it (as of ColdFusion 9 anyway).

If you want to do video work with Adobe ColdFusion, you should look at other open source libraries which you can call from within ColdFusion, such as [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/).  It's not as simple as the `CFVIDEO` tag in Railo, but it's widely used and supported and shouldn't be too difficult to implement if you're unable to use Railo for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use CF's own [`<cfmediaplayer>`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSE66DB0CD-E16D-49e7-AAEE-F51F9580554E.html)  for this?  Does the Railo one do something the CF one doesn't?  (Serious question: I've never used either tag on either platform).

Comment: no, 'cause cfvideo tag can do things to videos files, and it has functions similar to ImageInfo() and isImageFile(), but for Videos.

Comment: Ah, OK, fair enough.  Sorry for the bum-steer.  Not sure why someone voted me up if the answer is wrong!  Sounds stupid, but can people pls vote me down.  I'd delete the answer but it's perhaps good to leave it here so people don't think the same thing I did...